# Issue with Random.Next() not choosing random values

Tags: c#, .net

As I understand it, Random.Next() uses the system time for getting the seed, but when iterating through a loop very fast the system time hasn't changed or has hardly changed, giving me the same "random" number. I'm attempting to use random to select starting positions to begin writing bytes for about 2 seconds of static here and there to music files, 30 different positions are selected, but they're almost the same. I'm getting almost continuous static from the beginning, broken about 3 times for just a few seconds before it resumes playing the music normally at around 30 seconds in; which isn't what I want, I need it spread out throughout the entire clip. "int pos" is the problem, its not random, each starting position is nearly identical to all the others, so I have a prolonged amount of static, not static randomly spread throughout the music. My randoms are also static.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int pos = rand2.Next(75000, 4000000 /*I've been too lazy to get the file length, so I'm using 4000000*/ );
    for (int x = 0; x < 500000/*500000 is a little over 2 seconds of static*/; x++)
    {
        byte number = array[rand.Next(array.Length)];
        stream.Position = pos;
        pos++;
        stream.WriteByte(number); 
    }
}
```

I assumed that it would take 5 seconds or so to make each write (on my slow CPU), which would be enough time for the next random to give me a position that isn't identical to or extremely close to the previous one. As it stands, each time I seem to be getting an initial position of about ~90000 (first few seconds of music); and all of the next ones are within 20 seconds of that. So my question is, what do I need to modify/do differently in order to achieve my desired result? I'd like a couple seconds of static scattered throughout the entire clip, not clustered together.

I have a byte array which stores my hex digits, which are randomly selected, that appears to work fine, its just the randomness of the writing positions isn't random at all, they're all in extreme proximity.

```
byte[] array = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F };
```

Thanks.

P.S. I know I should have using blocks for the FileStream, I'll add it when I get around to it.

Comment: Could you use thread.sleep(1000) before generating random no? because your program pause for 1 second due to this random no changed.

Comment: The nested for loop should about require 5 seconds before finishing, so int pos will have 5 seconds of time elapsing before being randomized again. Which is why I don't understand why its not even close to being random.

Comment: I'm inclined to think the issue is something along the lines of what Jonathan Rupp has suggested. Have you actually stepped through the code, looked at the value of `pos` on each iteration, and verified that the values are all very close together? This seems very unlikely to me; I wager you will find the values are spread out pretty evenly between 75000 and 4000000. It is the *result* that likely appears "not random" by virtue of being compressed in scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 500000 bytes is about 2 seconds of audio, and you're starting somewhere between 75000 and 4000000, you're starting between 0.15s and 8s into the song.  That explains why you're not hearing any static after about 10s into the song.  Try using the actual file size (minus 500000) as the upper bound of the rand.Next call used to populate `pos`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this; I'll try using the file size and see if I get the desired result, if it works I'll mark this as the accepted answer. EDIT: Yeah, that works perfectly, thank you. Now everyone knows how I selected my username, it fits.

Answer (score 2):

When you write :
    int pos = rand2.Next(75000, 4000000)
If your file is stereo 16 bits 48KHz, then 4000000 / (2*2*48000) = 20 seconds
of sound. Use the file size, it's easy. You shouldn't be lazy :-) .
But if you 'Add' noise you shouldn't replace the file value, but rather add to
it a random value.
And why have a noise amplitude of only 16 / Byte ? and fixed ? using number = rand.Next(Amplitude)
 would seem fine to compute the added noise.
Note also that you're creating two white noises, one on each channel.

Comment: My understanding of how these files contain the data is extremely limited. Are you saying to read the bytes and then modify them slightly, so that instead of replacing the music with static I have it as a background noise? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Go and find about sound file format on the web. in 16 bits stereo 48000, each sample is 2 bytes=16bits=-32767 --> 32768 and represents the sound pressure value for this 1/48000 slice of time. Left and right samples are together (L1R1L2R2L3R3....). And yes *add* the noise, so use Stream.read, then set Position again to write. Since you operate at byte and not int16 level, the noise should range 0->255. Remember to handle overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when generating random numbers . It was generating the same values. The following simple code solved my problem.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
   lock (syncLock)
   { // synchronize
       return random.Next(min, max);
   }
}
```

You will use is like below:

```
int rn = RandomNumber(0, 10); //for example
```

Comment: Assuming the poster's code isn't multi-threaded, the lock won't have any practical affect.

Answer (score 0):

First, Random.Next does not use system clock to generate a random number. Random number is generated on the basis of seed provided and the default constructor(parameterless) uses the system clock as seed but it only set the system clock as seed.
Correct me if I am wrong but it looks u r getting random numbers but these numbers are close enough to produce almost same sound and u want your numbers to be scattered with large margin(difference between consecutive random numbers). To achieve this I suggest you to use a minimum threshold. If difference between consecutive number is less than threshold either try to generate next one or adjust the value to satisfy the threshold. A code can better explain what I want to say.

```
int RandomNumber(Random rand,int? lastRandomNumber, int min, int max, int threshold)
        {
            var number = rand.Next(min, max);
            if (lastRandomNumber.HasValue && Math.Abs(lastRandomNumber.Value - number) < threshold)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Actual:{0}", number);
                if (lastRandomNumber.Value < number)
                {
                    number += threshold;
                    if (number > max)
                        number = max;
                }
                else
                {
                    number -= threshold;
                    if (number < min)
                        number = min;

                }
            }
            return number;
        }
```